# how to compress Image List before downloading to client in silverlight application

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, compression, client-server

In my silverlight application there is thousands of `jpg`, `bmp` and other format images in Database (on server side). based on many conditions, a list of selected images(sometimes more than a thousand) should transferred to client and displayed to end user.

To improve the process we used paging method. therefore whenever user clicks 'Next Page' button, we get next page images from server side.

I'm trying to improve the process using a method like **image compression in server side and then decompression in client**(in silverligh application).
Is there something like a client-server compression algorithm or tool or any other method to do this work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the highest bandwith savings by converting all images to a smaller size, lower resolution, low compression level and JPEG format.

Find out what size/resolution/compression level is just acceptable for the end-user.

If you send a JPEG over the wire, the decompression is done automatically by the JPEG renderer when displaying the image on the client side.

The library functions in .Net should allow you to do all that.

See [Set JPEG Compression Level (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as an example.

Comment: thanks, but I can't use automatic JPEG renderer because of many processes which are done in client and after images downloaded. of your  solutions(size/resolution/compression level), I have resized images as you mention above. but because of low speed I need more and better improvement. it seems that a good compression method is required which compresses  batch images!